# Continuously push elasticsearch on docker data to S3

Tags: git, docker, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance, which has a docker container running elasticsearch. Every day, some process pushed new documents into elasticsearch. I want to push those documents to an S3 bucket the day after the document has entered elasticsearch.

I found this solution online:

https://github.com/AckeeDevOps/elasticsearch-backup-to-s3

I am new to elasticsearch, docker, and aws, so the steps provided in the git repository are not detailed enough for me to know what to do, so I am wondering if someone could verify my understanding of steps I need to take, below:

0) Clone the above git repository and set the following parameters:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_URL url with port where your elasticsearch runs, for example localhost:9200
S3_URL contains address in S3 where to store backups
    bucket-name/directory
S3_ACCESS_KEY
S3_SECRET_KEY
CRON_SCHEDULE cron schedule string, default '0 2 * * *'
```

1) On my EC2 instance, do

```
docker build https://github.com/AckeeDevOps/elasticsearch-backup-to-s3
```

2) Then, I need to change the existing docker container that is running to have additional options

```
/var/backup/elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 -d elasticsearch -Des.path.repo=/var/backup/elasticsearch
```

3) I do not understand what this line does:

```
docker run --link elasticsearch:elasticsearch -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL="elasticsearch:9200" -e SNAPSHOT_VOLUME="/var/backup/elasticsearch" -e S3_URL="your S3 url" -e S3_ACCESS_KEY="your S3 access key" -e S3_SECRET_KEY="your S3 secret key"
```

Is there a more accepted/documented way of having elasticsearch data pushed to an external bucket continuously? Any piece of advice and/or illumination of the steps one would need to take to use the repository above would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to backup elastic search to S3 or do you want to push the standalone documents into S3?

Comment: Hi! I want to push standalone documents every day.

Answer (score 3):

### Docs Referred

[elasticsearch-backup-snapshot-and-restore-on-aws-s3](https://medium.com/@federicopanini/elasticsearch-backup-snapshot-and-restore-on-aws-s3-f1fc32fbca7f)

[opendistro](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/elasticsearch/snapshot-restore/#amazon-s3)

### Dockerfile

```sh
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2

#this is to tell that we are passing these arguments at runtime
ARG ENV_VAR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG ENV_VAR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ${ENV_VAR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ${ENV_VAR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
ENV xpack.security.enabled 'false'
ENV  xpack.monitoring.enabled 'false'
ENV xpack.graph.enabled 'false'
ENV xpack.watcher.enabled 'false'
ENV discovery.type 'single-node'
ENV bootstrap.memory_lock 'true'
ENV indices.memory.index_buffer_size '30%'

RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install --batch repository-s3
RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore create
RUN echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin s3.client.default.access_key
RUN echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin s3.client.default.secret_key
```

### register.json

```
{
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "elk-backup-codeaprendiz"
  }
}
```

### restoresnapshot.json

```
{
  "indices": "kibana*,my-index*",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false,
  "include_aliases": false,
  "partial": false,
  "rename_pattern": "kibana(.+)",
  "rename_replacement": "restored-kibana$1",
  "index_settings": {
    "index.blocks.read_only": false
  },
  "ignore_index_settings": [
    "index.refresh_interval"
  ]
}
```

### snapshotsetting.json

```
{
  "indices": "kibana*,my-index*,-my-index-2016",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false,
  "partial": false
}
```

#### Build image and deploy

- Build new image

```sh
docker build  \
--build-arg ENV_VAR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID> \
--build-arg ENV_VAR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY> \
--tag=codeaprendiz/elasticsearch .
```

- Check the images present

```sh
$ docker images | grep "codeaprendiz/elasticsearch"
codeaprendiz/elasticsearch                      latest              f06a06d5fd8a        36 seconds ago      796MB
```

- Running the image

```sh
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9600:9600  codeaprendiz/elasticsearch
```

#### Register

- Register your repo at S3

```sh
$ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @register.json "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my-s3-repository"
{"acknowledged":true}
```

#### Taking Snapshots

- Taking a snapshot

```sh
$ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @snapshotsetting.json "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my-s3-repository/firstsnap?wait_for_completion=true"
{"snapshot":{"snapshot":"firstsnap","uuid":"VpRaTS-eRr6TLqIOi9Zw2w","version_id":7060299,"version":"7.6.2","indices":[],"include_global_state":false,"state":"SUCCESS","start_time":"2020-05-16T14:13:06.219Z","start_time_in_millis":1589638386219,"end_time":"2020-05-16T14:13:06.624Z","end_time_in_millis":1589638386624,"duration_in_millis":405,"failures":[],"shards":{"total":0,"failed":0,"successful":0}}}
```

- Corresponding docker logs

```sh
$ docker logs -f friendly_fermi
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-16T14:13:06,646Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.s.SnapshotsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "676c35dac6af", "message": "snapshot [my-s3-repository:firstsnap/VpRaTS-eRr6TLqIOi9Zw2w] started", "cluster.uuid": "Crq-wvoIQmuzm920sZr8MA", "node.id": "Q_xnc6qyRxy-BbvRLQNwlg"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-05-16T14:13:08,852Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.s.SnapshotsService", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "676c35dac6af", "message": "snapshot [my-s3-repository:firstsnap/VpRaTS-eRr6TLqIOi9Zw2w] completed with state [SUCCESS]", "cluster.uuid": "Crq-wvoIQmuzm920sZr8MA", "node.id": "Q_xnc6qyRxy-BbvRLQNwlg"  }
```

- Request your snapshot

```sh
$ curl -X GET  "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my-s3-repository/firstsnap"
{"snapshots":[{"snapshot":"firstsnap","uuid":"VpRaTS-eRr6TLqIOi9Zw2w","version_id":7060299,"version":"7.6.2","indices":[],"include_global_state":false,"state":"SUCCESS","start_time":"2020-05-16T14:13:06.219Z","start_time_in_millis":1589638386219,"end_time":"2020-05-16T14:13:06.624Z","end_time_in_millis":1589638386624,"duration_in_millis":405,"failures":[],"shards":{"total":0,"failed":0,"successful":0}}]}
```

- To check the status of snapshot

```sh
$ curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/_status"                
{"snapshots":[]}
```

- To check all the snapshots

```sh
$ curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/_all"
{"my-s3-repository":{"type":"s3","settings":{"bucket":"elk-backup-codeaprendiz"}}}
```

- To see all the snapshots in a repository

```sh
$ curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my-s3-repository/_all"
{"snapshots":[{"snapshot":"firstsnap","uuid":"VwFvTv3nSKOD5K8J3EBE2A","version_id":7060299,"version":"7.6.2","indices":[],"include_global_state":false,"state":"SUCCESS","start_time":"2020-05-14T14:45:46.358Z","start_time_in_millis":1589467546358,"end_time":"2020-05-14T14:45:46.561Z","end_time_in_millis":1589467546561,"duration_in_millis":203,"failures":[],"shards":{"total":0,"failed":0,"successful":0}}]}
```

#### Restore your snapshot

- To restore a snapshot

```sh
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @restoresnapshot.json "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my-s3-repository/firstsnap/_restore"
{"snapshot":{"snapshot":"firstsnap","indices":[],"shards":{"total":0,"failed":0,"successful":0}}}
```

[Link to git - basic](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/docker-kitchen/tree/master/task-003-elastic-search/7.7/backup-and-restore)

[Link to git - intermediate](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/docker-kitchen/tree/master/task-003-elastic-search/7.7/bkp-restore-sample-data)